# Seu binário não oferece suporte para iPad

Tags: html, ios, xml, apache-cordova, itunes

Realizei a criação de um "app web" utilizando o phonegap, ao enviar o mesmo para o itunes, obtive o seguinte aviso: "**Seu binário não oferece suporte para iPad**", como proceder?

Alguém poderia me ajudar, pois se uso uma licença para testes (*provisioning file Development*) o mesmo funciona perfeitamente, mas quando tento procurar meu app na Apple Store, ele não é nem mostrado.

**Meu xml:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
id="meuId" 
version="3.0.3"
versionCode="3">

<name>Corp</name>
<description>
    meu App
</description>

<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="target-device" value="handset" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-sqlite" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm"/>
<platform name="android">
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="img/icon/App_Icon/icon-57.png" width="36" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="img/icon/App_Icon/icon-72.png" width="48" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="img/icon/App_Icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="img/icon/App_Icon/icon-120.png" width="96" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="img/screen/Default-portrait-iphone.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="img/screen/Default-portrait@2x-iphone4.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="img/screen/Default-568h@2x.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="img/screen/Default-portrait@2x-iphone6.png" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="img/icon/App_Icon/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="img/icon/App_Icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="img/icon/App_Icon/icon-120.png" width="114" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="img/icon/App_Icon/icon-152.png" width="144" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="img/screen/Default-portrait-iphone.png" width="320" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="img/screen/Default-portrait@2x-iphone4.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="img/screen/Default-568h@2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="img/screen/Default-568h@2x-landscape.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1334" src="img/screen/Default-portrait@2x-iphone6.png" width="750" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="2208" src="img/screen/Default-portrait@3x-iphone6+.png" width="1242" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="img/screen/Default-Portrait-ipad.png" width="768" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="img/screen/Default-Landscape-ipad.png" width="1024" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="2048" src="img/screen/Default-Portrait@2x-ipad.png" width="1536" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1536" src="img/screen/Default-Landscape@2x-ipad.png" width="2048" />
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true" />
    </feature>
</platform>
<icon src="img/icon-152.png" />
<gap:splash src="img/screen/splash.jpg" />
<access origin="*" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De fato, pelas configurações que você apresentou, não há suporte mesmo para iPad, de acordo com o [`target-device`](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.3.0/configuring_preferences.md.html#_ios_only), só é compatível com **handset**. Caso pretenda torná-lo universal, altere para:

```
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
```

Agora, acredito que "*Seu binário não oferece suporte para iPad*" é só um alerta exibido após o envio, certo? Pelo que entendi, você já conseguiu aprovação do seu aplicativo pela Apple, porém, o fato de não conseguir localizá-lo na loja tenha relação com ele estar disponível somente para a "loja de iPhones".

Note que as lojas podem variar de acordo com o aparelho que você acessa. Então, se estiver acessando de um iPad, você não o encontrará.

Comment: Por conta disto então, agradeço o feedback @Paulo, irei atualizar meu xml, pelo que pesquiser ela usa esse preference para especificar em que loja estará disponível.